# Two Calls to Function, One Failing - Javascript - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Hi I am working on my first chrome extension and am running into a problem when calling a function. I have a function that sends a prompt to the ChatGPT API and returns a value. When I call it this way:

```
// Execute if "Context Menu" from background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (
      message.type === "CM_SpellingGrammar" ||
      message.type === "CM_Task" ||
      message.type === "CM_Answer" ||
      message.type === "CM_WordCount" ||
      message.type === "CM_Rewrite" ||
      message.type === "CM_Clarity" ||
      message.type === "CM_Scholar" ||
      message.type === "CM_Tone" ||
      message.type === "CM_StructureOrganization"
     ) {
    CM_result = message.type;
    sendRetrieve();
  }
});
```

This is a call in my contentScript.js file using inputs from the Context Menu read from my background.js file.

However when I try to call the same function like this:

```
function TESTCLICKED(event) {
  CM_result = "CM_SpellingGrammar";
   sendRetrieve();
}
```

The request seems to be send to ChatGPT API but the console just returns "null"

**Why is this happening? The function calls seem to be the same with the same inputs.**

Here is my function to send a prompt to ChatGPT API:

```
function sendRetrieve() {
// If there's an active text input
if (
  document.activeElement &&
  (document.activeElement.isContentEditable ||
    document.activeElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "TEXTAREA" ||
    document.activeElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT")
) {
  // Set as original for later
  originalActiveElement = document.activeElement;
  // Use selected text or all text in the input
  textOriginal = 
    document.getSelection().toString().trim() ||
    document.activeElement.textContent.trim();
  text =
    document.getSelection().toString().trim() ||
    document.activeElement.textContent.trim();
} else {
  // If no active text input use any selected text on page
  textOriginal = document.getSelection().toString().trim();
  text = document.getSelection().toString().trim();
}
if (!text) {
  alert(
    "No text found. Select this option after right-clicking on a textarea that contains text or on a selected portion of text."
  );
  return;
}

console.log(originalActiveElement);


// SPECIAL CASES PROMPT
// Alter the message based on task from user for prompt
if (CM_result === "CM_SpellingGrammar") {
  text = "Revise the following for grammar and spelling:\n\n[" + text + "]\n\n If the provided text cannot be revised for spelling or grammar return 'NoneNullNoneNullNone'";
}  else if (CM_result === "CM_Task") {
    text = text;
} else if (CM_result === "CM_Answer") {
  text = "If the following is a question, answer it. Else return 'NoneNullNoneNullNone': [" + text + "]";
} else if (CM_result === "CM_WordCount") {
    var wordcountInput = prompt("Please provide a description of the word count adjustment you would like made:\n\nHint: It often helps to provide an upper and lower limit.");
    if (wordcountInput) {
      text = "Adjust the word count of the following based on 'Word count adjustment':\n\n[" + text + "]\n\nWord count adjustment: [" + wordcountInput + "]\n\n If you cannot complete this task return 'NoneNullNoneNullNone'";
    } else {
      return
    }
} else if (CM_result === "CM_Rewrite") {
  text = "Rewrite the following to convey the same meaning in different structure, words, and organization: [" + text + "]";
} else if (CM_result === "CM_Clarity") {
    text = "Revise the following for clarity:\n\n[" + text + "]";
} else if (CM_result === "CM_Scholar") {
  text = "Revise the following to meet the standards of an extremely scholarly written paragraph, up to the highest academic quality:\n\n[" + text + "]";
} else if (CM_result === "CM_Tone") {
  var toneInput = prompt("Please provide a tone description to complete the revisions:");
  if (toneInput) {
    text = "Adjust the tone of the following based on 'Desired tone':\n\n[" + text + "]\n\nDesired tone: [" + toneInput + "]\n\n If you cannot complete this task return 'NoneNullNoneNullNone'";
  } else {
    return
  }
} else if (CM_result === "CM_StructureOrganization") {
  text = "Revise the following for structure and organization:\n\n[" + text + "]";
}

// Define the prompt to send to the API
let userPrompt = {
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{ role: "user", content: text }],
  temperature: 1,
};


document.body.style.cursor = "wait";

// Send a POST request to the endpoint with the prompt and headers
fetch(endpointUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(userPrompt),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // Use original text element and fallback to current active text element
    const activeElement =
      originalActiveElement ||
      (document.activeElement.isContentEditable && document.activeElement);
    if (activeElement) {
      if (
        activeElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "TEXTAREA" ||
        activeElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT"
      ) {
        responseMessage = data.choices[0].message.content;
        console.log(responseMessage);


        // SPECIAL CASES RESPONSE
        // Dont add a period if the original prompt didn't end in one
        if ((
            CM_result === "CM_SpellingGrammar" || 
            CM_result === "CM_Rewrite") && 
            textOriginal.charAt(textOriginal.length - 1) !== "." && 
            responseMessage.charAt(responseMessage.length - 1) === "."
          ) {
          responseMessage = responseMessage.slice(0, -1);
        } 
        // Check for quotation marks and remove them
        if (
            responseMessage.charAt(0) === '"' &&
            responseMessage.charAt(responseMessage.length - 1) === '"'
          ) {
          responseMessage = responseMessage.slice(1, -1);
        }
        // Alert if CM_Answer prompt was not a question
        if (CM_result === "CM_Answer" && responseMessage.includes('NoneNullNoneNullNone')) {
          alert(
            "It appears the prompt provided was not a question. Try submitting a question."
          );
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          return;
        } 
        // Alert if CM_Tone prompt was not a valid tone
        if (CM_result === "CM_Tone" && responseMessage.includes('NoneNullNoneNullNone')) {
          alert(
            `It appears the provided tone could not be applied to the text or the prompt provided was not a valid tone. Try submitting a valid tone including but not limited to:\n\n${toneExamples}`
          );
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          return;
        } 
        // Alert if CM_WordCount prompt was not a valid tone
        if (CM_result === "CM_WordCount" && responseMessage.includes('NoneNullNoneNullNone')) {
          alert(
            "It appears the provided word count adjustment was invalid. Try submitting a valid word count adjustment description."
          );
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          return;
        } 
        // Alert if CM_GrammarSpelling prompt was not able to be corrected
        if (CM_result === "CM_SpellingGrammar" && responseMessage.includes('NoneNullNoneNullNone')) {
          alert(
            "It appears the prompt you provided was not able to be corrected for grammar or spelling. Please try a different prompt"
          );
          document.body.style.cursor = "default";
          return;
        } 
        // Insert Response
        if (CM_result === "CM_Answer") {
          activeElement.value = activeElement.value + "\n" + responseMessage;
        } else {
          activeElement.value = responseMessage;
        }



      }
    } else {
      // Alert reply since no active text area
      alert(`ChatGPT says: ${data.reply}`);
    }

    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
  });
}
```

Comment: 1) Looks like you call `fetch` in your content script, in which case it won't work and you'll need to do it in the background script (service worker) or in the action popup, see [this example](/a/55292071). 2) onMessageExternal won't see messages from a content script that runs in the default `world`, so remove the `External` part.